# Cannot install vet package with go get

Tags: go

I'm running following command:

```
$ go get -u golang.org/x/tools/cmd/vet
```

> package golang.org/x/tools/cmd/vet: cannot find package
>   "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/vet" in any of:
>               C:\Development\Software\go\src\golang.org\x\tools\cmd\vet (from $GOROOT)
>   C:\Development\Software\go\downloaded_packages\src\golang.org\x\tools\cmd\vet
>   (from $GOPATH)

I can't really understand how `cannot find package` makes sense with `get`. It is supposed to get the package from internet. Why is it looking for it locally?

Comment: It downloaded the repo, and the vet command didn't exist locally in the codebase. The `vet` tool is included in the go distribution be default.

Comment: @JimB If it's included by default, then I guess it should find it in `GOROOT`?

Comment: No, because the source in GOROOT has a different path. (`$GOROOT/src/cmd/vet`), but it should already be built.

Comment: @JimB So is there no need to install `vet` using `go get`? I'm following [this guide here](https://www.wolfe.id.au/2015/03/05/using-sublime-text-for-go-development/) to install `gosublime` and it lists installing `vet` in instructions.

Comment: No, that guide is just out of date.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@JimB summed it up in the comments - you don't need to install `go vet` separately.

But just for completeness, the direct answer to OP question is that the code for the `go vet` command no longer lives at `golang.org/x/tools/cmd/vet` (see https://golang.org/doc/go1.2#go_tools_godoc - and since that the code has moved to GitHub).

So when you run: `go get -u golang.org/x/tools/cmd/vet` it appears that it is git cloning the `golang.org/x/tools/cmd` package and then trying to compile `golang.org/x/tools/cmd/vet` which is resulting in an error ("cannot find package...") because the "vet" part doesn't exist - it moved out a while ago.  (`go get` first downloads/clones the code and then attempts to compile the package on your local system.)

And all of that is to say, you probably already have `go vet` - try typing "go vet -h" and if it works (you should see something like: "usage: vet ..."), you're set.